# Getting HTTP 505 from Glassfish 4.1 servlet when trying to connect from Android

Tags: java, android, http, servlets, glassfish

I have Java server with servlet (running on Glassfish 4.1 that comes with NetBeans 8). And I have an Android app (API 19) running on physical device (Prestigio Grace).

The servlet responds to GET (and POST) requests by sending some data back in JSON. If I make the request from browser (FF 40.0.2) (while server is running) it works fine. If I do the same request from my Android app (with the same URL) I get status code 505.

The code in Android app that does the GET request:

```
public String makeHttpGetRequest(String urlStr) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(urlStr);

    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    if (responseCode == 200) {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream());
        String response = readUntilEndOfStream(isr);
        isr.close();
        return response;
    } else {
        throw new IOException("bad status code : " + responseCode + " , from: " + urlStr);
    }
}
```

And the code I use in servlet:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    handleRequest(request, response);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    handleRequest(request, response);
}

private void handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
    try {
        UniversalAddress adr = params2UniversalAddress(request.getParameterMap());
        AvgPricesRenovationState avgPrices = db.getAvgPricesAndRenovationState(adr);
        if (avgPrices == null) { //prices for that address are not stored. Now we have to calculate them from scratch
            avgPrices = getNewAvgPrices(adr);
        }
        response.getWriter().write(avgPrices.toHttpParams());
    } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        printMissingParametersResponse(request, response);
    }
}
```

Why am I getting status code 505 and how to fix this?

Comment: What value has the urlStr paremeter?

Comment: Figured it out. Problem was that Android was connected via wifi which is a different LAN subnet than via cable (the server). So the requests never made it to the sever.

Comment: That was also what I was thinking. Probably you used localhost instead of the local IP of the machine in which the server runs.